# freeradius and expired user configuration

Tags: ldap, openldap, freeradius

in freeradius ldap-module it exist an Expiration attribute which I can map to an LDAP attribute, but in which format? The Documentation is not clear. I've the following LDAP attributes, which one works?

```
sambaKickoffTime: 1580252400
krb5ValidEnd: 20200129000000Z
shadowExpire: 18290
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for implementing a password policy with password expiration. Since you've tagged your question with [openldap] you should look into man-page [slapo-ppolicy(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy) - especially how to use attribute *pwdMaxAge*.

If you've implemented this in your OpenLDAP server there is no need to configure anything in FreeRADIUS.